# IE not wrapping text around images

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a page with this HTML:

```
<p>
    <img src="images/ih01.jpg" width="80" height="110" align="left" />
    This course overs basic human anatomy and physiology, including the major
    body systems and their functions. When you have completed this course you
    will be able to identify major body components and their core physiological
    functions.
</p>
```

And this is how it displays in Firefox 3, Chrome 1.0 and IE7: (Click for full size)

http://fisher.spadgos.com/stuff/ie-align-fail.png

You can see that IE is not wrapping the text around the image even though it's aligned left. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
<img src="images/ih01.jpg" style="float: left; height: 110px; width: 80px; " >
```

instead of align. The align attribute is [deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_IMG.asp).

Comment: Man, I never knew IE7 stopped supporting align. Cheers.

Comment: You beat me by like 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

First off, "align" is deprecated.  You'll want to use the CSS float property here.

```
<p>
    <img src="images/ih01.jpg" style="float:left;height:110px;width:80px" />    
    This course overs basic human anatomy and physiology, including the major
    body systems and their functions. When you have completed this course you
    will be able to identify major body components and their core physiological
    functions.
</p>
```

It's time to take a "time out" to [learn about floats](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/)!

Comment: hehe I know about floats and CSS - this is code from our CMS that a non techie created with a WYSIWYG, and I was hoping to be able to avoid re-writing all that code!

Comment: Ah, WYSIWYG web editing in the days before DIVs and CSS.  Got to love it.

Comment: If the align attribute is the only problem, you can probably fix it with a search/replace.

Comment: what if you had multiple paragraphs after that paragraph? I have situation where the image is "taller" than the paragraph and there is a blank space between paragraphs in Internet Explorer.  No float/clear combination has fixed that issue.